# How to Drop image over image view using fingure touch

Tags: android, image, android-layout

I am very much new this issue.I want to make application like this.look at the image below,This is a brief summary of my requirement.

[image]

ok so top there is a image view.After user capture image from camera in `OnActivityResult` I am displaying captured image on main image view. Below that image view there is a `HorzontalScrollView`, Inside `HorzontalScrollView` i have put couple of images,like hat,spects etc...

ok so What i want is, user should be able to drag any image from `HorzontalScrollView` and can be able to put that small image on main image view.

Any guide/tutorial will be appreciated from guys who have worked on such functionality

Thanks

Comment: you could look first at standard dnd API, it should work fine for your case http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/drag-drop.html

Comment: @AlexeyA. ok thanks,let me check